# Check message has been written to kafka topic using command line

Tags: apache-kafka

**Firstly, please note that using the java consumer API is not an option. Why it is not an option I am unable to disclose, but I must be able to do the following using a shell command.**

I have a topic that I have written a message to, and I can confirm this is the case if I run `./kafka-console-consumer.sh` with the `--from-beginning` option, but since this starts a consumer then the command gets stuck and requires manual intervention with a SIGINT. I have come close using `--timeout-ms`, however this is not ideal as unless I select a high value there is the possibility that the dump of the data is unreliable.
I would like to dump the output of console-consumer in such a manner that it can be grepped, ***or*** a suitable alternative method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write to Kafka, you can set [in the producer](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs) `acks` which is the level of guarantee you want from the broker that the message has been received and written by the local broker and/or all replicas.

If you use this then you have no need to try and consume from the topic to determine if the record was written or not. This sounds like a really bad idea to try and do.

If you absolutely must use a command-line tool to do this (which, is not a good idea) then use `kafkacat` which can consume from any offset for any number of messages, e.g.:

- Consume (`-C`) five messages (`-c 5`) from the beginning (`-o beginning`), or exit (`-e`) when end of partition is reached

  ```
  kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -t mytopic -o beginning -e -C -c 5
  ```
- Consume (`-C`) ten messages (`-c 10`) from the end (`-o -10`), or exit (`-e`) when end of partition is reached

  ```
  kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -t mytopic -o -10 -e -C -c 10
  ```
- Consume (`-C`) one messages (`-c 1`) at offset 42 (`-o 42`), or exit (`-e`) when end of partition is reached

  ```
  kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -t mytopic -o 42 -e -C -c 1
  ```

Comment: Unfortunately using the API is not an option, I am aware it is in almost all other cases a bad idea, but using the command line is the only option here. Kafkacat seems like a good mention, however in this instance I have asked and I will not have permission to use it. Thank you anyway though.

Comment: How are you _writing_ records to Kafka? Are you not using the Producer API?

Comment: In this context, by piping input in to the stream via `echo [string] < ./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list [brokers] --topic [topic]`. I understand it's not usually done, but it is indeed necessary due to existing design that cannot be changed.

Comment: Additionally, accepting this as the answer since it is unlikely that circumstances which constrain myself will apply to anyone else, and KafkaCat would be the ideal solution. In the unlikely event they are limited only to inbuilt shell and kafka functionality, it looks like --timeout is the only real option.